# MVC3 Want Clientside Validation to trigger for two fields when one of the two is modified

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, client-side

I am creating an MVC3 website and added a couple of security questions to the "My MVC Application" Registration routine in the form of dropdown boxes. I created a custom validator to check the second dropdown box and if the selected item is the same as the first then it shows an error message.

My problem is that the clientside validation triggers as soon as the second dropdown box loses focus. After the error is displayed, ideally, I should be able to change the selection in the first dropdown box and the validation error message for the second dropdown box should go away. But, of course, changing the first dropdown box does not trigger the clientside validation routine for the second dropdown box and the error does not go away.

I would appreciate it if someone who is well versed with the internalls of unobstrosive Ajax validation routines would guide me to a solution so that when the selection of one dropdown box changes the validation routine of both dropdown boxes is triggered.

Thanks a bunch for any pointers.

Comment: if you cannot be bothered to post code why should people help you. please at least post what you have.

Comment: samack, I didn't mean to be incomplete. I am just new and learning my way around to being effective in conveying the question. Thank you very much for looking at my question. There is one answer that I think will answer my question. If it doesn't then I will try to include more details. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391020/validate-other-field-without-causing-infinite-loop) and my answer, you will see code for client-side validation where changing one field will trigger validation on another field, and will then stop after both fields' validation has run.

Comment: Thank you very very much for the answer. I am a bit new and might take me a short while to apply your solution to my situation. I will mark as answered as soon as I have done that. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again for the solution. It works. A couple of alternatives were also offered elsewhere.  The first one from the author of the article that I used to create the custom validators is adding a jquery change handler and calling valid() function on the other dropdown box:

Comment: $('#SecurityQuestion1').change(function() {
$('#SecurityQuestion2').valid();
}); The second one from another forum that appears to actually change the settings of the jquery validator: var settngs = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
settngs.onfocusout = function (element) { $(element).valid(); if(element.id =="dropdown1")  $("#dropdown2").valid()  }; I haven't tested the second method yet. It may provide valuable insight to the innerworkings of jquery validation methods.